# Animation broken after clear transformations

Tags: animation, rigging, pose-mode

[Blend File](https://pasteall.org/blend/ecf5ce1f76fb455d9028d6341c0a3177)

I've made an animation called Run where my character is running, then I proceeded to modelling tab and cleared rotation and other transformations so the character would stand in the initial pose.

Something happened with my bones orientation. As a result my character animation inverted and it doesn't look like running. How can I fix it? Below example of animation is attached.

[image]

I am a newbie to 3D.

Comment: hello do you have the version before applying?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately not. But that was a regular quick run